# How to join list with first and last being the joining char in Python?

Tags: python

```
>>> ll=('x','y','z')
>>> '|'.join(ll)
'x|y|z'
>>> '|'+'|'.join(ll)+'|'
'|x|y|z|'
```

How can I get `'|x|y|z|'` in a simpler way ?

---

```
str1 = '|' + '|'.join(header) + '|'
str2 = '|' + ' - |'*len(header)
str3 = '|'.join(('', *dat, ''))
```

I think "str3" is much easier to read than "str1".

Comment: define simpler? This is already only 20 characters...

Comment: Less operations. like `'|'.join(('','x','y','z',''))` which come without two external string appending.

Comment: ``f"|{'|'.join(ll)}|"``? I wouldn't call it *simpler* if I ever had to review it more than two hours after writing, though...

Comment: Or simpler for human to read like `f"|xx|"` above

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you're missing a ```"``` if am not mistaken

Comment: `('', *ll, '')` is about 1.5x slower than the accepted answer with `['', *ll, '']` for `10920 < len(ll) < 602880` on my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So using your comment as inspiration:

```
'|'.join(['', *ll, ''])
```

I'm not sure this is really *less operations*, but maybe it looks cleaner?

Comment: And it saves one character, what a deal! :)

Comment: For short lists, `'|'+'|'.join(ll)+'|'` is only slightly faster than the more readable solution but for `len(ll) > 100` the speed ratio climbs to 2 and stays in the 2 to 2.5 range up to `len(ll) = 2160228` where I stopped testing

Comment: @JoachimWagner I'm not getting anywhere near those disparities, at `len(ll) == 3_000_000` I'm getting 29.7 ms for `'|'+'|'.join(ll)+'|'` and 39.2 ms for `'|'.join(['', *ll, ''])`. Smaller lists have narrower disparities

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for your measurements. It may indeed depend on the system, Python version, what strings are in `ll` and other factors.